# Apache Tomcat en Docker y VPS

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, error404, vps

Tengo un contenedor de Apache Tomcat ejecutándose en un contenedor de Docker y toda esta infraestructura bajo un VPS, pues bien, cuando ingreso en mi navegador la IP pública de mi VPS junto al puerto 8081 que es por donde está escuchando Tomcat, este me devuelve un error 404. Supongo que habrá que configurar Apache Tomcat para tener acceso a las carpetas o el index que suelta al principio por lo menos, ¿qué debería hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]